# how to capturing delete key-press on macbook

Tags: jquery, ios

```
// keyboard down window check.
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
     onKeyDownHandler(event);
}, false);

function onKeyDownHandler(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
  var focus_id = e.target.id;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
       case 46: // delete
        //delete item
        alert("why i cant get this work on mac?");
        break;
}
}
```

why my key-press wont work on mac ? can anyone show me how to make key-press delete work on mac?

Answer (score 3):

Backspace (8) and delete (46) perform the same way on Mac.

Updated code:

```
// keyboard down window check.
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  onKeyDownHandler(event);
}, false);

function onKeyDownHandler(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  var focus_id = e.target.id;
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 46: // Delete
    case 8: // Backspace
      alert("Delete pressed");
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: `.keyCode` would be helpful but I have this problem in 2022 and it's deprecated now. Do you have any alternative solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: @Julz use `key` property and match with the key name like this `if( key == "Delete") { // your code }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = document.getElementById('myInput');

input.onkeydown = function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if( key == 8 || key == 46 )
        return false;
};
```

=> As per Related Jquery tag -

```
jQuery(function($) {
      var input = $('#myInput');
      input.on('keydown', function() {
        var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

        if( key == 8 || key == 46 )
            return false;
      });
});
```